# Concurrency task never execute "then()" nor throws exception (C++/CX UWP)

Tags: exception, concurrency, uwp, task, c++-cx

I have a problem using Concurrency::task to list some devices from my code :

A use to use this code last year with visual studio 2015 :

```
Concurrency::create_task(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(Windows::Devices::Midi::MidiInPort::GetDeviceSelector()))
    .then([](Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationCollection ^midiDeviceCollection) {

        for (Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation^ portInformation : midiDeviceCollection){
            //do stuff with device
        }
    });
```

But several month later, ... today, I have to update my app (in the meantime I switched to VS2017). So I reopened and updated the project, sadly this code no longer work the way it should. Breakpoints set in the "then()" part are never reached and the code continues to be executed without errors as if my task were never called.

I wondered if was an error when executing DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync that didn't let the "then()" part to run. After some research on tasks (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd492427.aspx) I found a way to catch exceptions while tasks are running, so I transformed my code into :

```
    IAsyncOperation<DeviceInformationCollection^>^ deviceOp = DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(MidiInPort::GetDeviceSelector());
    Concurrency::task<DeviceInformationCollection^> deviceEnumTask = Concurrency::create_task(deviceOp);

    deviceEnumTask.then([](Concurrency::task<DeviceInformationCollection^> t){

        try{
            DeviceInformationCollection ^midiDeviceCollection = t.get();

            for (DeviceInformation^ portInformation : midiDeviceCollection) {
                 //do stuff with device
            }

        }catch (Platform::Exception^ e){
            //do stuff with device
            OutputDebugString(e->Message->Data());
        }

    });
```

Same result, the app never enters in "then()" and no Exception is thrown :-( .

So my question is : What is the problem here ? This piece of code is the most common way to list devices, I have seen it on several places all other the web (moreover it worked last year in my case), so I should have made a mistake or missed something elsewhere.

Is this the good way to catch errors in tasks ?

More info : This code is called directly in MainPage constructor, just after InitializeComponent(); . I'm running VS2017, Target Platform Min Version is 10.0.10240.0 and Target Platform Version is 10.0.15063.0. The app is build and tested on a desktop x64 machine.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Edit :**

Thanks to Sunteen Wu and David Pritchard (see below) I have been able to figure out where the problem came from. The code above actually works, as stated in the answers and is really clear and complete after adjusting the error handling as proposed by David. During my tests my break point was also placed on the right line. But in fact, without realizing it, I used some blocking code deeper in the "//do stuff with device" (not visible here). This was bloking the MainPage constructor avoiding it to continue execution until invoked tasks are completed... Apparently tasks are still linked with main thread execution and were not ran as long as the MainPage construction was not ended, what in my case never happened -> deadlock !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the MIDI part of your question. I can speak to the exception-handling code.

First - I doubt you're seeing an exception from `FindAllAsync`, as an unobserved exception will usually just crash the app (or break to debugger).

Second - the exception-handler above appears to mix up the two types of continuations:

- *Type 1:* regular continuation, to continue work once an async method returns its result.

  e.g., `deviceEnumTask.then([] (DeviceInformationCollection ^) { ... })`
- *Type 2:* exception-handling continuation, to deal with any exceptions in the task chain.

  e.g., `deviceEnumTask.then([] (Concurrency::task<void> t) { ... })`

Your original code sample used type 1 but without a type 2 included, and therefore cannot handle any exceptions.

Your revised code sample uses a non-standard continuation (neither type 1 nor type 2), and will likely never be called.

What you want is to use both 1 and 2 in concert, like this:

```
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Midi;
Concurrency::create_task(
    DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(MidiInPort::GetDeviceSelector())
).then([](DeviceInformationCollection ^midiDeviceCollection) {
    for (DeviceInformation^ portInformation : midiDeviceCollection){
        //do stuff with device
    }
}).then([] Concurrency::task<void> t) {
   try {
      t.get();
      OutputDebugString(L"No exceptions seen");
   }
   catch (Platform::Exception ^e) {
      OutputDebugString(e->Message->Data());
   }
});
```

Comment: This explaination on error handling is very clear, that was something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

> Same result, the app never enters in "then()" and no Exception is thrown

By testing on my side, when setting break point inside `task::then`, its delegate can be executed successfully as follows:
[image]

The app do enter in the delegate. If you set the break point just at the `task::then` code line and using `F10` to step over, it will skip the delegate since the `task::then` method returns immediately, and its delegate doesn't run until the asynchronous work completes successfully.Details please reference [Consuming an async operation by using a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps#consuming-an-async-operation-by-using-a-task).

> Is this the good way to catch errors in tasks ?

According to [Handling errors in a task chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps#handling-errors-in-a-task-chain), it seems like the way you are trying to catch errors is correct. If the asynchronous operation causes an exception to be thrown,the continuation will never execute. You will get any exceptions that have been transported down to the task by `task::get`.

You could also check if "no longer work" is caused by there is no `MidiInPort`. Try to get the devices size as above picture showed.